# How to speed up Undo's/Redo's in Textmate?

Tags: macos, terminal, textmate

I know this is possible because I changed the setting a few years ago. I recently reformatted my Mac Pro and cannot remember what I did. There's a setting, that I know is not in Textmate, something like a refresh or something in Terminal.

Does anybody have any idea what I'm referring to?

It made it so if I have to undo say around 60 history steps in my code editor, it would go through them about ~3x faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Terminal, run this command:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 0
```

Then log out and log in again. The fastest setting obtainable via System Preferences is 2 (lower numbers are faster), so you may also want to try a value of 1 if 0 seems too fast. You can always visit the Keyboard & Mouse System Preferences panel to undo your changes.

Boom.